# Control space between ticks discrete x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
df1 <- data.frame(dose=c("D0.5", "D1"),len=c(4.2, 10))
ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=dose, y=len, group=1)) + geom_line()+geom_point()

df2 <- data.frame(dose=c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"), len=c(4.2, 10, 29.5))
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=dose, y=len, group=1)) + geom_line()+geom_point()

df3 <- data.frame(dose=c("D0.5", "D1", "D2","D3"), len=c(4.2, 10, 29.5,35.5))
ggplot(data=df3, aes(x=dose, y=len, group=1)) + geom_line()+geom_point()
```

[image]

What i am trying to do is to  keep the distance between each variable on x axis the same irrespective of how many variables present on X axis.
df1 has only two variables and the distance between the ticks are far more compared to other plots..you could also see that the distance is not the same between df2 and df3 as well. The closest i came to do this was by adding `scale_x_discrete(expand = expand_scale(add = c(0.1, 0.1)))` which does not seem to work. uniformly

I am trying to plot each DF on one pdf, which is why i cannot use grid, wrap objects...

Comment: To have constant space between ticks on axes with different numbers of ticks you need different sized plotting windows. In an interactive session, this generally means manually resizing the windows. If saving plots as image files, then you can specify different widths for the files - you'll need some constant amount of space for the margins and then add a fixed amount per tick on the x axis.

Comment: I could factor it using somthing like this `theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1), "cm"))` is that what you suggest?, my goal ultimately is to do this inside a script..not interactively.

Comment: Yes, setting the margins explicitly would help to know what constant value to use, and then it doesn't much matter what your `scale_x_discrete` is (though the added expansion padding will need to be accounted for along with the margin). After that, it's just specifying the right widths in `ggsave`, `width = const + per_tick * n_ticks`.

Comment: I am still murky on how to set that do you have an working example?

Comment: Are you expecting to have different width graphs?

Comment: so my lowest level(on x axis) is 2 and highest is 10 so yes, but for example here i went up to 4 levels.

Comment: OP, I saw you have deleted some of the answers to your question here.  While none may have answered your question in the desired way, [I suggest you read the post on deletion criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), since I would recommend that most of them be retained, as they are still useful even if they are not the best to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The plot will always distribute your discrete values across the x axis of the plot, so there's not a simple way to add space to the right of the plot *consistently*.  You could try to use the `expand=` argument of `scale_x_discrete()`; however, that's going to be really difficult to see consistency and get the spacing right.  If you have `NA` values for a discrete x position in your plot, `ggplot2` will still create the plot and distribute or spread out the x values on the x axis as if there was data there.  We can use that to our advantage to offer a solution to your problem.

First, here's a function that will add some empty rows to your data frames based on a `blank_df`.  You need to setup `blank_df` to contain blank information for as many values of `dose` that you would conceivably have.

```
add_empty_rows <- function(df) {
  blank_df <- data.frame(dose=c("D0.5", "D1", "D2", "D3"), len=rep(NA, 4))
  if(nrow(df) < nrow(blank_df))
    return(rbind(df, blank_df[((nrow(df)+1):nrow(blank_df)),]))
  else
    return(df)
}
```

The function works by checking the number of rows in the data frame in question (`df`) and if it's less than `blank_df`, then the empty rows are added from `blank_df`.

You can then integrate this into making your plot.  If we did nothing else but plot this data frame resulting from `add_empty_rows(df)`, we would get a lot of blank discrete ticks on the x axis.  I'm adding a line to add only the breaks (tick marks) that are contained in the original data frame to the plot.  This results in creating the empty space (but not the ticks and labels) on the right side of the plot.

```
make_plot <- function(d) {
  p <- ggplot(data=add_empty_rows(d), aes(x=dose, y=len, group=1)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_discrete(breaks=d$dose)
  return(p)
}
```

Here's the plots you get as a result.

```
make_plot(df1)
make_plot(df2)
make_plot(df3)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]